# BigQuery/SQL: Split String based on the second dot from right

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

### update: there are situations that dot position that might not be the best solution.

I got a column of website.

```
website
www.abc.google.com
www.bcd.google.com
wwww.efd.google.co.za
```

I want to transform it into

```
    website
    google.com
    google.com
    google.co.za
```

Anyone knows how to split based on the '.' position from the right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regexp_substr()` does exactly what you want:

```
select regexp_substr('www.abc.google.com', '[^.]*[.][^.]*$')
```

Answer (score 2):

> Split String based on the second dot from right

you can use `regexp_extract(website, r'(\w+\.\w+)$')`

or

> there are situations that dot position that might not be the best solution.

```
net.reg_domain(website)
```

if apply to sample data in your question - the last one gives below output

[image]